# Get data from Berkeley DB with Java

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation, blob, berkeley-db

I have a basic Java program which can list data from Berkeley DB database. The question is how I can list the database scheme to see what object are available? Unfortunately I don't have information what is the design of the database.